# Pyinstaller is not working with pygame, making an NotImplemented Error?

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller

So i have a problem, whenever i try to use Pyinstaller with Pygame, it won't work, instead after a second, it says that it stopped working. I ran a test program before (consisting of a block moving up and down and a block following your cursor) and it worked just fine. However, i tried implementing some text using `pygame.font.Font` function and suddenly it stopped working. I tried using a try function to see if it could catch it, and nothing. I tried using no font, nothing. This also works as a regular .py file as well, just not as an executable. I'll include further info as needed if need be.
              Thanks in advance!
EDIT:i was able to produce an error thanks to kaktus_car letting me know that there was an update to  pygame, here it is:

```
Traceback (Most recent call last):
"test.py", line 20, in <module>
File "site-packages\pygame\pkgdata.py", line 50, in getResource
File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1134, in resource_exists
File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1404, in has_resource
File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1472, in _has
NotImplementedError: Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type 
[1276] Failed to execute script test
```

Comment: Which font have you used?

Comment: I am using default, i put in `None` as the argument.

Comment: Try it this way, with `SysFont` -> `new_font = pg.font.SysFont("Times New Roman", 18)`

Comment: it did not work unfortunately, ran fine in my IDLE, but not as an .exe (apologies for the time it took, PC had another surprise update)

Comment: Sorry to hear that, no problem. I had similiar issue and this done the trick. If you are using `python 3.8` make sure you update `pygame` to `2.0.0.dev6` or newer if available. Nothing else springs to my mind...

Comment: I will try that, didn't know there was an update, thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah, check on their official site, also update with `pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6`, or newer, because simple `pip install` or `update` will give you `pygame 1.9.6` (at least was like that). No problem, Hope you will succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i managed to figure it out! What i did was i instaed used a different application than pyinstaller. Instead, i used cx_Freeze. If you are having this kind of problem as well, the link is [Here](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) the directions are rather clear and you have the option to include files, so if you have a game with made graphics, it can include them.